# Equivalence/Similarity of matrices over domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, $R$ some domain with $R\subsetneq K$. Take some square-matrix $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(R)$ with $n>1$, and suppose the matrix $B \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(R)$ is equivalent to $A$ over $K$, i.e. there are $S,T  \in \operatorname{GL}_n(K)$ such that $A = SBT$. My question is which conditions need to be imposed *on the ring* to gurantee that $A = S'BT'$ with unimodular $S',T' \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(R)$. What happens if we replace equivalence by similarity?

I'm under the impression that I once read that a PID suffices regarding the similarity..

Comment: To guarantee that $S,\,T \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(R)$ for all such $S$ and $T$, $R = K$ is necessary. Take $B = A$, $x \in K \setminus R$, $S = x\cdot I$, $T = x^{-1}\cdot I$. I think you want to guarantee that there are $S,\,T \in \operatorname{Mat}_n(R)$ such that $A = SBT$ whenever $A$ and $B$ are equivalent over $K$, don't you?

Comment: regarding your first two sentences, i want B to be an *arbitrary* matrix equivalent to A. and yes A,B need to be in $\operatorname{Mat}_n(R)$.

Comment: As I read it, your text says $\bigl(\forall A,\,B\in\operatorname{Mat}_n(R)\bigr)\bigl(\forall S,\,T\in\operatorname{GL}_n(K)\bigr)(A=SBT\Rightarrow S,\,T\in\operatorname{Mat}_n(R))$. I think you can't have that without $R=K$. If you want $\bigl(\forall A,\,B\in\operatorname{Mat}_n(R)\bigr)\Bigl(\bigl(\exists S,\,T\in\operatorname{GL}_n(K)\bigr)(A=SBT)\Rightarrow\bigl(\exists S',\,T'\in\operatorname{Mat}_n(R)\bigr)(A=S'BT')\Bigr)$, I think that could be guaranteed by some conditions on $R \subsetneq K$.

Comment: Yes you are right, the second statement is what i want, i will try to correct it in my original posting.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the two following remarks shed some light on your question.

Notation: if $R$ is a ring, $\mathrm{GL}_n(R)$ is the group of invertible matrices over $R$, i.e. the group made up of matrices $A$ such that $\mathrm{det}(A)$ is invertible in $R$. If $R$ is a ring and $A$ is a matrix, $I_k(A)$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by the $k \times k$ minors of $A$.

1. If $K$ is a field and $A, B \in \mathrm{Mat}_{m,n}(K)$, then there exist $M \in \mathrm{GL}_m(K)$, $N \in \mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ such that $B = MAN$ if and only if $\mathrm{rank} A = \mathrm{rank} B$.
2. (Smith normal form) If $R$ is a PID and $A, B \in \mathrm{Mat}_{m,n}(R)$, then there exist $M \in \mathrm{GL}_m(R)$, $N \in \mathrm{GL}_n(R)$ such that $B = MAN$ if and only if $I_k(A) = I_k(B)$ for all $k \geq 1$.

For example, if $L/K$ is a field extension and $A, B \in \mathrm{Mat}_{m,n}(K)$ are two matrices that are equivalent over $L$, then they are equivalent over $K$. The same is true for similarity.